# No debuggable applications

Tags: android

I'm building an android app (using Android Studio 1.1.0) and the device I'm trying to test my app is Samsung note 10.1 N8000(Api 16). When I click the bug button, everything is complied successfully but under Android tab under devices it says No debuggable app. I have tried various solution but none is working.

Event log says this :

```
7:09:54 AM Session 'app': running
7:11:25 AM Gradle build finished in 28 sec
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fatima.selfify"
    android:launchMode="standard">

    <application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fatima.selfify"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug{

            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop com.fatima.selfify
Waiting for process: com.fatima.selfify
```

Comment: Are you running any other instance of AS or Eclipse? Does your device show up in Android Monitor?

Comment: Did you try another device (or two)? Sometimes devices are modified by OEM (Samsung) and have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file has two   tags nested within...possibly because of this its not compiling..

Comment: see your application tag in manifest there are two application tags nested within each other